Horizontal and vertical stabilizer aspect ratio for large trainer RC aircraft
I am designing the empennage of a large RC aircraft. Does the aspect ratio for the horizontal and vertical stabilizers make a significant difference? Would it be better to make them with a smaller chord length and wider, or vice versa? This is not an aerobatic aircraft, closer to a trainer plane.
Thanks
